# Expand width to take remaining width of parent div

Tags: html, css

An example of my code can be found on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WdZgV/

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header_div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #bbb;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header_div">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want is that when you resize the window width to less than 1000px the `.menu` div resize to the size of the parent div.

So as an example:

If you have your window width as 900px, the `.logo` div has 200px and the `.menu` div has 700px.

Is there anyway i can do this with CSS, or i need to use Javascript?

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/ there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes — remove the `float`, don't specify `width`, and set `overflow` to `hidden`. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/3F4eW/); `.menu` becomes:

```
.menu {
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Andoni Roy Use this

```
.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;    
    height: 100px;
    background: #bbb;
      }

.menu {
    float:right;    
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background: #999;
      }
```

Comment: The .logo div must have 200px.

Comment: that's it! but i don't need the `float: right`. Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to play with floating properties but specifying the parent width and display to table.

Like in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/745/

You would end up having something like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header_div">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header_div {
 width: 1280px;
}

.header {
 display: table;
}

.logo {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 280px;
}

.menu {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 1000px;
}
```

You could specify width in percentages.